# Copy a variable number of values to another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste

I'm trying to take a range (lets say C:C), go through all the cells with value and paste them in another spreadsheet.

My target is to copy a variable number of values (because I don't know how many values I would have in C:C) to another sheet, so I have a new range with all the values (where there are no repeated values).

How to code the If statement (for a variable number of values)?

```
Sub Test_1()
    ' Go through each cells in the range
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Data_storage")

    For Each rg In Worksheets("Data").Range("C:C")

        If rg.Value = "Client 1" Then 'Instead of "Client 1" should be a variable value because "Client 1" will be a repetead value in C:C 
            copySheet.Range("C2").Copy 'Starting the counter in C2
            pasteSheet.cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValue
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: in your original (in Column C) you might have duplicate data ? and you only want to copy unique ID values to your "Data_storage" sheet ?

Comment: clarify with an example

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel does not have a built in function for pulling out unique values like that. You have to get your list, add the first item to an array, then for each subsequent item, check the entire list to see if it on there already and if not add it. If you are still struggling, let me know and I will show you my own code I use for this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your values in "Data" worksheet:

- are in column "C"
- start from row 1, with a "header"

then you can try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_1()
    Dim sourceRng As Range, pasteRng As Range, cell As Range

    Set pasteRng = Worksheets("Data_storage").Range("A1") '<--| set the upper-left cell in "paste" sheet

    With Worksheets("Data") '<--| reference "source" sheet
        Set sourceRng = .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| set the "source" range to columns "C:D" from row 1 down to last non empty cell in column "C"
    End With

    With sourceRng '<--| reference "source" range
        .Sort key1:=.Range("a1"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Range("B1"), order2:=xlAscending, header:=xlYes '<--| sort it by its column 1 and then by its column 2
        pasteRng.Resize(.Rows.Count).value = .Resize(, 1).value '<--| paste its column 1 values to "Paste" sheet column 1
        pasteRng.CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1) '<--| leave only unique values in "paste" range
        Set pasteRng = pasteRng.Range(pasteRng.Offset(1), pasteRng.End(xlDown)) '<--| skip "paste" range header
        For Each cell In pasteRng '<--| loop through unique values in "paste" range column 1
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.value '<--| filter "source" range column 1 with current unique value
            .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy '<--| copy "source" range" column 2 filtered cells
            cell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True   '<--| ... and paste/transpose them aside current unique value in "paste" range
        Next cell
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| .. show all rows back...
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sort them, you can record a macro of something like this:

- Select column C
- Home ➤ Find & Select ➤ Constants
  [image]
  <sub>(source: [contextures.com](http://www.contextures.com/images/formatformulas04.png))</sub>
- Copy and paste the selection to the other sheet
- Data ➤ Remove Duplicates
  [image]
  <sub>(source: [contextures.com](http://blog.contextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/removedups02.jpg))</sub>

P.S. I used #3 from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) :]

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can also be useful, especially if you plan more complicated filtering or calculation:

```
Public Sub CopyUnique(rngSource As Range, rngDestinationFirst As Range)
    If rngSource Is Nothing Or rngSource.Worksheet.UsedRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim dctValues As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dctValues = New Scripting.Dictionary ' Requires Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim rngSourceUsed As Range: Set rngSourceUsed = Application.Intersect(rngSource, rngSource.Worksheet.UsedRange)
    Dim varCell As Variant: For Each varCell In rngSourceUsed.Cells: Dim rngCell As Range: Set rngCell = varCell
        If dctValues.Exists(rngCell.Value) = False Then
            dctValues.Add varCell.Value, varCell.Value ' varCell.Formula may be also interesting depending on the business logic
        End If
    Next varCell
    Dim varValues() As Variant: ReDim varValues(0 To dctValues.Count - 1, 0 To 0)
    Dim i As Long: i = LBound(varValues, 1)
    Dim varValue As Variant: For Each varValue In dctValues.Keys
        varValues(i, 0) = varValue
        i = i + 1
    Next varValue
    rngDestinationFirst.Resize(dctValues.Count, 1).Value = varValues
End Sub

Public Sub TestCopyUnique()
    CopyUnique ActiveSheet.Range("C:C"), Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End Sub
```